# Two values in the same column

Tags: php, sql

I have two columns with different values:

[image]

And I need to echo those two values into one column, like that:

[image: IP is brackets]

Printing method:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr>
              <td scope="row">' . $row["id"].'</td>
              <td>' . $row["data"] .'</td>
              <td>' . $row["ip"] .'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could do that?

Comment: Hint:  string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this

```
echo '<tr>
        <td scope="row">' . $row["id"].'</td>
        <td>' . $row["data"] . '(' . $row["ip"] . ')</td>
      </tr>';
```

Comment: Indeed like this. Thank you! And sorry for the silly question

Comment: The last dot is redundant.

Comment: @RacilHilan Only if I merge the last 2 bit together, but if you like it that way thats cool by me

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. String concatenation is a very wasteful operation for memory and CPU. Ah, and that's bad for the environment and global warming :)

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two cells:

```
<td>' . $row["data"] .'</td>
<td>' . $row["ip"] .'</td>
```

Into one:

```
<td>' . $row["data"] . '(' . $row["ip"] . ')</td>
```